# Print the Web Service's Response in java code

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to create a web service client using wsimport tool. It generates the clientside stubs. In my code i am trying to print the web service's result. I try the following code.

```
import com.cdyne.ws.weatherws.WeatherSoap;
import com.cdyne.ws.weatherws.Weather;
import com.cdyne.ws.weatherws.WeatherReturn;
public class WeatherClient1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Weather we=new Weather();
        WeatherSoap ws=we.getWeatherSoap();
        WeatherReturn wr=ws.getCityWeatherByZIP("10021");
        System.out.println(wr);
    }
}
```

It doesn't cause any error or exception. It print the following result.

```
com.cdyne.ws.weatherws.WeatherReturn@4e280c
```

I need to print the responses seperately.

Comment: Your println method is simply calling wr.toString, which doesn't appear to output a meaningful value.  You will need to print each property of the wr object individually.

Comment: Could you please explain me how can i do this?

Comment: What are the values within the object that you want to print?